# How to delete an image from a Windows Phone album?

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I'm working on a Lens app for Windows Phone 8.  I would like to allow my users to delete their image from my app.

Is this possible or doesn't Microsoft allow third party developers this type of access?

Answer (score 0):

You have only read access to user's pictures in phone library. If you want app for deleting pictures also then you need to save them inside your application.

Comment: Can you elaborate more?